# Moment js unexpected behaviour for timezone

Tags: momentjs

While using moment js I observed that moment.tz().format() is not returning abbreviation always which breaking regex post this time format.

```
moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('z')  // "PDT"     (abbreviation)
moment.tz('Asia/Magadan').format('z')         // "+11"     (3-char offset)
```

What is the factor on which this behaviour depends? for which location or is it random?

I see that this zone will be cached by moment js. Is there cached in browser somewhere ?

Comment: Probably whether tz has a specific name, like EST, or PDT, or just defaults to offset

Comment: Not all timezones have an abbreviation.